# Angular error, in npm build [$injector:nomod] Module 'testApp' is not available

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Studying and practicing about npm build, im trying to compile my script using npm run build and i got an error

[$injector:nomod] Module 'testApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

any advice. thanks

```
app.js

import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import './services/router.js';

angular.module('testApp', [
  'ui-router'
]);

-----------------------------

my roter.js

'use strict';
angular
  .module('testApp')
  .config([
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$stateProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'components/views/homepage.html',
        controller: 'productController'
      })

      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'components/views/about.html'
      })

      .state('product', {
        url: '/product/:id/:name',
        templateUrl: 'components/views/product.html',
        controller: 'productViewController'
      })
}]);
```

Comment: the injected ui router shoud be `ui.router` here is an example [Using ES6 modules with angular](http://blessanmathew.com/2015/04/14/using-es6-modules-with-angular.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change

From

```
angular.module('testApp', [
  'ui-router'
]);
```

To

```
angular.module('testApp', [
  'ui.router'
]);
```

Comment: Hi sir @sajeetharan, sorry but can you be more specific? thanks.

Comment: There is a spelling issue you should use . Instead of -